# How cast Expression<Func<T1,bool>> to Expression<Func<T2,bool>>?

Tags: c#

How cast `Expression<Func<T1,bool>>` to `Expression<Func<T2,bool>>`?
**Notice that both T1 and T2 has same interface.**

Comment: You can't.  The cast will always be invalid, because no `Expression<Func<T1,bool>>` will ever actually be a `Expression<Func<T2,bool>>` instance.

Comment: You need to visit the expression and replace the parameter with the base interface

Comment: Or create a new expression that uses `Convert` assuming you can convert from `T1` to `T2`.

Comment: If both T1 and T2 have the same interface, then create an interface for them (say `interface IT1And2`), have them explicitly implement the interface, and use `Expression<Func<IT1And2>, bool>>`

Answer (score 0):

### THIS IS AN EXAMPLE SOLUTION, DONT USE IT IN REAL CODE

This will break if `childExpression` uses something else than `Base` properties. This will break if you have many parameters (demo visitor is implemented in the simpler way as possible). This can break in lots of cases, it should only be used for explanation purposes.

### Now, the explanation

This task can be accomplished by visiting the Expression and replacing the parameter to a new one:

```
class Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Child : Base { }
```

Let's assume you have an `Expression` for `Child` that only uses `.Name`:

```
var childExpression = (Expression<Func<Child, bool>>)(e => e.Name == "works!");
```

We can create a new parameter for type `Base` instead of `Child`:

```
var newParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Base));
```

Extract the old body:

```
var newBody = childExpression.Body;
```

Well, this has a problem: old body is using a reference to the old parameter inside, we need to replace it with the new one.

```
class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ParameterExpression _newParameter;

    public ParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression newParameter)
    {
        _newParameter = newParameter;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return _newParameter; // forget about the old one, return the new
    }
}
```

So then we can get our body with proper references:

```
var body = new ParameterReplacer(newParameter).Visit(childExpression.Body);
```

And combine the results in a perfectly typed `Expression<Func<Base, bool>>`:

```
var expressionForBase = Expression.Lambda<Func<Base, bool>>(body, newParameter);
```

And, of course, it works:

```
var predicate = expressionForBase.Compile().Invoke(new Base
{
    Name = "works!"
}); // true!
```

Comment: Blindly returning `_newParameter` without checking `node` seems dangerous. More importantly though, I don't get the impression from the question that one type is a subclass of the other, in which case this approach won't work.

Comment: @hvd yes it definitelly is, this was a fast and minimal working example

Comment: @IvanSanz-Carasa Just because you were able to create a *single* working example doesn't mean it's okay to provide a solution that breaks in all sorts of other situations, besides that *one* example.

Comment: @hvd Note that even with the target type being the base type of the original type it *still* isn't safe.  The original expression could have used a member defined in `Child`, although as you note, they might not be in the same inheritance chain to begin with.

Comment: this is the exact case described by OP, stop being so rude. If you have a better approach to explain him the concepts of expression parameter replacing, ill be glad to see it @Servy

Comment: @hvd Unconditionally replacing the parameter is fine if and only if the delegate type has only one parameter, which happens to be the case in this example.  It does prevent the solution from scaling to additional parameters.

Comment: @IvanSanz-Carasa No, it's *not* the exact case described by the OP.  And explaining to you why you have provided an incorrect answer isn't rude.  Just stating that your answer is correct and that you don't care about fixing the problems with it on the other hand...

Comment: @Servy The expression can contain a lambda expression containing more parameters, can it not?

Comment: @IvanSanz-Carasa Providing a working solution *is not possible*.  Providing a solution that just doesn't work, and refusing to acknowledge that it has any problems, doesn't change that.  At best, you're just wasting the readers time, at worst, they don't realize that your solution doesn't actually solve the problem and they go on to use it, only to realize much later when things start breaking that it's not a working solution.